# Laravel ToDo List with Livewire

Tags: php, laravel

I need some help. I recently started with a test project to make a basic todo list with Laravel Livewire. All is good but I have at the end with edit function I am getting an error when deleting a step within a Todo of Undefined offset: 0 highlighting this specific line of code: $step=$this->steps[$index];. Below is the code

```
public function remove($index)
{
  $step=$this->steps[$index];
  if(isset($step['id']))
  {
    Step::find($step['id'])->delete();
  } 
  unset($this->steps[$index]);
}
```

The $index value is passed through by edit-step.blade.php file as shown below:

```
@foreach ($steps as $step)
    <div class="form-group row" wire:key={{ $loop->index }}>

        <div class="col-lg-11">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Describe Step {{ $loop->index+1 }}" style="margin-bottom:2px;" name="stepName[]" value="{{ $step['name'] }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="stepId[]" value="{{ $step['id'] }}"/>
        </div>
        
        <span class="fa fa-times col-md text-md-left" style="color:red; cursor: pointer; margin-top:10px;" wire:click="remove({{ $loop->index }})"></span>

    </div>
```

Can you please help with where I am going wrong.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Not related to the issue but I think `wire:key={{ $loop->index }}` should be `wire:key="{{ $loop->index }}"` and since the **key** is to differentiate  items you better have to use `$step['id']` Otherwise, when you delete or add an item, you may encounter issues where the data aren't in the right div.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment yet!
You are passing `$loop->index` to the `remove` function instead of `$step['id']`.

Comment: The reason the loop index is passed to function "remove" is that the user can add new steps which do not have an ID during edit and also can remove any or all the steps

Comment: If you `unset` from the array, the **key** `0` will not exist anymore and your array will start at `1`

Comment: In addition, if I delete the steps in order of last in first out it works. But if I delete in the random order the first records that I choose to delete deletes but then I can the offset error

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I mean. It's normal it's working if you starts from the end since the key => index will still be relevant. But if you starts from any other place you will have a mismatch between key and the index: Here's what I meant earlier https://3v4l.org/GIroI

Comment: Instead of `$loop->index`, `@foreach ($steps as $key => $step)` should work